# Cursor to find word Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying a very simple cursor to find word count in a table with a like condition. My Cursor is:

```
declare @Engword varchar(max)
Declare @wcount int

DECLARE word_cursor CURSOR FOR
select distinct engtitle from Table
where a1 = 'EHD'
ORDER BY Engtitle;

OPEN Word_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Word_cursor
INTO @Engword;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
   Select @wcount = COUNT(*) from Table where engtitle like '%@Engword %'

   Insert into WordStatus(Engtitle,Estatus)
   Values(@Engword,@wcount)

   FETCH NEXT FROM Word_cursor
   INTO @Engword;
   end

CLOSE Word_cursor;
DEALLOCATE Word_cursor;
GO
```

I want to insert each word with their count which is comming from like condition in different table WordStatus.This cursor is inserting words in new table but all have same counts 0.
Plz Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you cannot have variables inside the quote strings `'%@Engword%'` is not valid. I think it should work if you change that line to this:

```
Select @wcount = COUNT(*) from Table where engtitle like concat('%', @Engword, '%')
```

Comment: concat' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Thank you for your help and giving idea...my cursor is now working absolutely fine after doing little alteration in your query.. Select @wcount = COUNT(*) from Table where engtitle like '%'+@Engword+' '+'%'

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense.  You are fetching the entire title from the table in the cursor.  Then you are checking if the title with a space following is in the table.  Happily, your titles are not misformed, so you do not get any match.

If you have a list of words, you can do what you want with a single query, and no cursors:

```
select w.word, count(t.engtitle) as NumWords
from Words w left join
     Table t
     on t.engtitle like concat('%', w.word, '%');
```

If you want words with separators, then do:

```
select w.word, count(t.engtitle) as NumWords
from Words w left join
     Table t
     on concat(' ', t.engtitle, ' ') like concat('% ', w.word, ' %');
```